# How can I get a WPF DataGrid column to bind to an enumeration?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I have a collection of items that I have bound to a WPF `DataGrid`. One of the columns needs to allow the user to select from an enumeration.  I have also created a separate class to hold user-friendly display strings for each of the enumeration values.

These are the types:

```
public enum UnitEnum { Metres, Hours, SingleValue };

public class UnitTuple
{
    public UnitEnum Unit { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}

public class CostItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public UnitEnum UnitID { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my view-model:

```
public static List<UnitTuple> AllUnitTuples = new List<UnitTuple>()
{
    new UnitTuple { Unit = UnitEnum.Metres, DisplayName = "Metres" },
    new UnitTuple { Unit = UnitEnum.Hours, DisplayName = "Hours" },
    new UnitTuple { Unit = UnitEnum.SingleValue, DisplayName = "Single Value" }
};

public List<CostItem> CostItems => new List<CostItem>()
{
    new CostItem() { Name = "Design", UnitID = UnitEnum.SingleValue },
    new CostItem() { Name = "Manufacturing", UnitID = UnitEnum.Hours },
    new CostItem() { Name = "Materials", UnitID = UnitEnum.Metres }
};
```

And this is the start of the XAML I am using:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGridCostItems"
    ItemsSource="{Binding CostItems}"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Cost Item Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Units"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Can anyone help me out with the remaining data-binding expressions (e.g. `ItemsSource`, `SelectedValueBinding`)?

I have been trying to follow the two examples shown below but am having trouble mentally mapping these examples to my code.

[Codeless two-way data binding](https://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/Codeless-two-way-data-binding-to-a-WPF-DataGrid)

[How to bind an enumerator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417728/how-to-bind-an-enumerator-or-variable-to-a-datagridcombobox-in-datagrid-in-wpf)

Following on from the answer by Aakanksha, I tried to get an `ObjectDataProvider` working but couldn't.  The problem I was encountering - which is that the `DataGridComboBoxColumn` apparently does not have the data context of the view-model - is explained here: [Cannot find governing FrameworkElement](http://wpfthoughts.blogspot.com/2015/04/cannot-find-governing-frameworkelement.html).

This same article suggested the use of `CollectionViewSource` instead. Attempting this solution has lead to the code below, which almost works: the combo-box column is correctly populated with the user-friendly display strings and when I select one to edit, I get a drop-down containing the user-friendly display strings for the enum.  All good.

The only part I now cannot get to work for the life of me is getting the newly selected value in the combo-box to persist back to the data-bound **CostItem**.

Can anyone suggest how to fix this last piece of the puzzle?

```
public enum CostUnit
{
    SingleValue,
    Hours,
    Metres
}

public class CostUnitTuple
{
    public EstimateCostUnitTuple( EstimateCostUnit enumValue, string displayString )
    {
        EnumValue = enumValue;
        DisplayString = displayString;
    }

    public CostUnit EnumValue { get; private set; }

    public string DisplayString { get; private set; };
}

public static class CostUnitAllTuples
{
    public static string GetDisplayStringFromEnum( CostUnit enumValue ) { ... }

    public static CostUnit GetEnumFromDisplayString( string displayString ) { ... }

    public static CostUnitTuple[] GetValues => new CostUnitTuple[]
    {
        new CostUnitTuple( CostUnit.Hours, "Hours" ),
        new CostUnitTuple( CostUnit.Metres, "Metres" ),
        new CostUnitTuple( CostUnit.SingleValue, "Single Value" )
    };
}

public class CostItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";

    public CostUnit Units
    {
        get => _units;
        set
        {
            _units = value;
            UnitDisplayString = CostUnitAllTuples.GetDisplayStringFromEnum( _units );
        }
    }

    public string UnitDisplayString { get; private set; } = "";

    private CostUnit _units;
}

public class UnitsOfMeasureConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture ) =>
        CostUnitAllTuples.GetDisplayStringFromEnum( (CostUnit)value );

    public object ConvertBack( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture ) =>
                    ((EstimateCostUnitTuple)value).EnumValue;
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public List<CostItem> CostItems { get; set; } 
    public AllCostUnits => CostUnitAllTuples.GetValues;
}

<Control.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <u:UnitsOfMeasureConverter x:Key="UnitsOfMeasureConverterKey"/>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="UnitsCollectionViewSourceKey" Source="{Binding AllCostUnits}"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Control.Resources>

<DataGrid
    ItemsSource="{Binding CostItems}"
    SelectionMode="Single">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Units"
                TextBinding="{Binding UnitDisplayString,Mode=OneWay}"
                SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Units,Converter={StaticResource UnitsOfMeasureConverterKey}}"
                DisplayMemberPath="DisplayString"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource UnitsCollectionViewSourceKey}}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your can use a converter to display enum in your datagrid.

```
public class EnumConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((Enum)value).ToString()
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return  null;
    }
}
```

And in your XAML, something like this:

```
Binding="{Binding UnitID, Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=EnumConverter}}"
```

Declare your "EnumConverter" in the resources section of your xaml file.

Comment: I don't think the missing converter is the main part of my problem. If I change all enums to ints in my code, I still can't get it to work. (But +1 because, yes, I will undoubtedly need a converter or a ToString() override somewhere.)

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways is:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{x:Static local:YourViewModelClassName.AllUnitTuples}" SelectedValuePath="Unit" SelectedValue="{Binding UnitID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: I'll experiment with this now. But it does feel like a 2nd class solution, because the DataGrid already has a combo-box column type that seems to be specifically designed to do what I want. I'd like to get that working, as much for future knowledge as anything.

Answer (score 0):

To bind enum to your `DataGridComboBox`

Add a `ObjectDataProvider` in the resources section.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="myEnumData" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="local:UnitEnum" />
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
```

And in the `DataGridComboBoxColumn` bind the `ItemsSource` like this,

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="MyHeader" DisplayMemberPath="EnumValue" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myEnumData}}" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding UnitID}"/>
```